# Trigger de bloqueio de INSER com condição e mensagem de erro

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de criar uma Trigger com uma condição que apenas não gerasse lançamentos de pagamento para um código de responsavel financeiro expecifico no sistema e que os demais deixasse passar e quando não gerasse para o código expecifico aparecesse uma mensagem de erro na tela do usuário.

```
CREATE TRIGGER noInsertTeste

ON FLAN 


INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM FLAN WHERE CODTDO = '00017431'

    DECLARE 

    printl ("Lançamentos não gerados pois o Responsavel TESTE não pode ser gerado lançamento.")

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charles, pelo que compreendi não é para permitir inclusão de linhas na tabela  FLAN quando o valor da coluna CODTDO for "00017431".

Ao construir procedimentos de gatilho é necessário ficar atento que eles são acionados para tratar uma ou mais linhas, ou mesmo nenhuma. De início te recomendo a leitura da série de artigos “[Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/08/18/armadilhas-na-programacao-de-trigger/)”.

Pelo fato do procedimento de gatilho poder receber mais de uma linha em um mesmo evento, se for para rejeitar uma ou mais linhas, então todo o bloco é rejeitado.

Eis código com sugestão inicial, que pode ser aprimorado.

```
-- código #1
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.noInsertTeste
     on dbo.FLAN
     instead of INSERT as
begin

-- verifica número de linhas a tratar
declare @NL int;
set @NL= (SELECT count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from INSERTED) as I);

-- encerra o processamento se não há linha para tratar
IF @NL = 0 return;

-- rejeita bloco se houver alguma linha com o código específico
IF exists (SELECT * from INSERTED where CODTDO = '00017431')
  begin
  PRINT 'Lançamentos não gerados pois o Responsavel TESTE não pode ser gerado lançamento.';  -- raiserror?
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  return;
  end;

-- inclui as linhas na tabela FLAN
INSERT on dbo.FLAN 
  SELECT * from INSERTED;

end;
go
```

Não tive a oportunidade de testar o código; pode conter erro(s).